# Django source files not updating when changing pages

Tags: javascript, django, django-viewflow

Using Django 1.11 with Viewflow-Pro 1.04

This is probably a very simple question, but I've spent hours googling and reading and have come up completely empty.

Each page of my app has various CSS/javascript files that it loads with script and link tags. However, when a user clicks a link and it redirects them to another page, the source isn't refreshed - it is still using the source from the previous page (which is often similar, but not the same).

Refreshing the page fixes it, as it pulls the correct source. But basically I'm having to refresh the page every time I get redirected to a new page.

This has proven hard to debug, since a lot of pages have the same source and so they "seem" to work correctly - but I think it only happens with links. If my view.py redirects users (using return render or similar) then it doesn't happen. It is just if a user clicks a link to jump from one part of my site to another.

Anyone have a clue what it could be? I would include code samples, but it's affecting my entire project - if some specific code would be helpful let me know.

This is an example of what one of my links looks like:

```
<a href="{% url 'dashboard:MOC_edit' MOC.id %}">{{ MOC }}</a>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Viewflow uses Django-Material frontend with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) to manage page scripts.

To adapt your page for Turbolinks ensure that scripts located in the `<head>` of a document. And 'turbolinks:load' event used to initialize it.

Ex: https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/viewflow/frontend/static/viewflow/js/viewflow.js